# Object.assign function does not work when called from $.getScript, but does when pasting contents

Tags: jquery, javascript-objects

I'm trying to tidy up my js code by including some parts as external js files, but it gives me mixed results.

In my JS script I have a var (options), which I also tried without var to use as a global scope variable

```
var options = {
        onSave: function () {
            fbEditor.toggle();
            formContainer.toggle();
            $('form', formContainer).formRender({formData: fb.formData});
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        disabledAttrs: ["description", "access", "className"],
        disableHTMLLabels: true
    };
```

I'm extending that var by using

```
Object.assign(options, {
    formData: somestuff;
});
```

I also have a very large chuck of data I want to include, I'm using another JS file for that, like so:

```
$.getScript("assets/js/pages/createform.js", function () {
    makeForms();
});
```

This is a summary of that content

```
function makeForms() {
    console.log("Script loaded");
    Object.assign(options, {
        inputSets: [
            {
                label: 'Leads',
                fields: [
                    {
                        "type": "header",
                        "subtype": "h1",
                        "label": "Buyer Form"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "label": "In what City are you looking to buy your new property?",
                        "subtype": "text",
                        "maxlength": "128"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]

    });
};
```

It shows the script IS loaded, but it just does not work. When I isolate the

```
Object.assign(options, {
  inputSets: [
    {
...
}
    ]
});
```

And add it to the original JS at the same place as the getScript position, it works as expected.

Does Object.assign not work when called within an included file?

EDIT:
I am now using some dirty hack where I just use a PHP include function which works for me. But I'd love to know the right way, if any.

This does not work:

```
...
        $.getScript("assets/js/pages/createform.min.js", function () {

        });
...
```

This does work:

```
...                                          
<?php include "assets/js/pages/createform.min.js"; ?>
...
```

Comment: `var = options`..? Do you mean `var options = {}`? I would assume your issue has to do with scope, but without seeing a complete example it's hard to say. Also note that this seems an over-complicated way of achieving a basic AJAX request.

Comment: Thank you @Rory, I edited / added to the post. It is a formbuilder(.online) project, which might be more clear now.